# How to use a user defined function in where clause in Oracle?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, user-defined-functions, oracle12c

I want to do something like this:

`SELECT subscription from TENANT where tenant_id = (select GET_TENANTID(12345) as tenant_id from DUAL);`

Here, `GET_TENANTID` is a **user-defined** function.
Also, `tenant_id` field is a `varchar2` type column.

I'm on Oracle 12c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work, but why not just do:

```
select subscription
from TENANT
where tenant_id = GET_TENANTID(12345);
```

One assumes that the types are the same.  If they are not the same, convert the number to a string.

Comment: It does not.
It gives: ORA-01722: invalid number 
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.
Can it be because tenant_id is varchar and sometimes GET_TENANTID returns null ?

Comment: No.  But it could be because `get_tenantid()` returns a number.

Comment: Thank you. I changed it to TO_CHAR(GET_TENANTID(12345)) and it worked.

Comment: " I changed it to TO_CHAR(GET_TENANTID(12345)) and it worked".  So what is the data type of SUBSCRIPTION.TENANT_ID ?  It sounds like to_char() is a band-aid and the real solution is to fix your function to return the correct, matching data type.